# Printing simple histogram horizontally

Tags: beginner, c, formatting

I am new to programming and want to know if this is really bad code. I know my variable names may seem arbitrary but I spent some time trying to get them right. I am struggling on that. Would you do this the same way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 100

void printHistogramHorizontally(int alphabetofline[]);

int main()
{
    int c,i,j;
    int alphabetofline[25];
    char line[MAXLINE];


    for(j=0; j< 26; j++)
        alphabetofline[j] = 0;


    for(i=0;i < MAXLINE -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        line[i] = c;

        switch (c)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                ++alphabetofline[0];
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                ++alphabetofline[1];
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                ++alphabetofline[2];
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                ++alphabetofline[3];
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
                ++alphabetofline[4];
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':
                ++alphabetofline[5];
                break;
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                ++alphabetofline[6];
                break;
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                ++alphabetofline[7];
                break;
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
                ++alphabetofline[8];
                break;
            case 'j':
            case 'J':
                ++alphabetofline[9];
                break;
            case 'k':
            case 'K':
                ++alphabetofline[10];
                break;
            case 'l':
            case 'L':
                ++alphabetofline[11];
                break;
            case 'm':
            case 'M':
                ++alphabetofline[12];
                break;
            case 'n':
            case 'N':
                ++alphabetofline[13];
                break;
            case 'o':
            case 'O':
                ++alphabetofline[14];
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
                ++alphabetofline[15];
                break;
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                ++alphabetofline[16];
                break;
            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                ++alphabetofline[17];
                break;
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                ++alphabetofline[18];
                break;
            case 't':
            case 'T':
                ++alphabetofline[19];
                break;
            case 'u':
            case 'U':
                ++alphabetofline[20];
                break;
            case 'v':
            case 'V':
                ++alphabetofline[21];
                break;
            case 'w':
            case 'W':
                ++alphabetofline[22];
                break;
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
                ++alphabetofline[23];
                break;
            case 'y':
            case 'Y':
                ++alphabetofline[24];
                break;
            case 'z':
            case 'Z':
                ++alphabetofline[25];
                break;
        }


    }


    if (c == '\n')
    {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }


    line[i] = '\0';

    printf("\n%s\n", line);

    printHistogramHorizontally(alphabetofline);

    return 0;

    }

    void printHistogramHorizontally(int alphabetofline[])
    {
    char const* alphaIndex[] =  {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G",
                                "H", "I", "J","K", "L", "M",
                                "N", "O", "P","Q", "R", "S",
                                "T", "U", "V","W", "X", "Y",
                                "Z"                          };
    int i, numOfX;
    i=numOfX=0;

    for( i = 0; i < 26; ++i )
    {
        printf("%s: ", alphaIndex[i]);

        while(numOfX < alphabetofline[i])
        {
            printf("X");
            ++numOfX;
        }
        numOfX = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- A character itself can serve as index. This observation greatly simplifies the reading loop:

  ```
  for(i=0;i < MAXLINE -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
  {
      line[i] = c;
      if (!is_letter(c))
          continue;
      if (is_upper(c))
          c = to_lower(c);
      alphabetofLine[c - 'a'] += 1;
  }
  ```

  Standard C provides `isalpha`, `isupper` and `tolower` functions, but I suggest you to implement them for practice. They are as simple as a couple of comparisons, and some addition and subtraction.

  - `alphabetofLine` is not a good name. I recommend `letter_histogram` or something to that respect.
  - I don't see how `j` is used.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was going through K&R exercises and the book has people do programming without many functions to get the hang of it. The way you did it was much better. I will practice them. Thank you about the comment for the alphabetofline, I was having so much trouble trying to name it. Also, J is used to initialize the alphabetofline to 0.